# Passing/Using Terminal Arguments with C

Tags: c, macos, file, terminal

So the purpose of my program is to simulate a chat- one text file contains responses (call it  r.txt) and I write my messages to another (call it m.txt). What I'm looking to do is write code for it in a c file using xcode, then call the program in my command terminal (I'm using Mac OSX). My question is- how does one pass multiple arguments to a C program using the terminal?

I see that in main theres 2 variables, int argc and const char* argv[]. So then does C use the array to account for multiple command line arguments? Cause essentially I'd do something like  "$(name of the program), file_name_1, file_name_2." How would I reference these in my C file?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: Each element of the array `argv` (read as: "argument values") at index `1` or greater is a C string containing one of the command-line arguments (`argv[0]` conventionally contains the name of the program).  The `argc` (read as: "argument count") tells you how many of those there are.

Comment: Okay I get you.. so then if I do something like "$(name of the program"), r.txt, m.txt", then argv[1] would be r.txt and argv[2] would be m.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `main` function is: `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])`.

The first one `argc` is the number of elements in the array `argv`. The first element `argv[0]` is the name of the program. After that you have the strings of each given parameters.

The command line (shell) separated the parameters (by default) with spaces. So `myprog foo bar` will result to `argv[0]="myprog" argv[1]="foo" argv[2]="bar"` (and here `argc=3`).

Several spaces are not taken in count. If you parameters contain spaces you have to use quotes (i.e. `myprog "arg with spaces" other "many   if wanted"`.